# How to exclude work module from the compile, when deploying to GAE?

Tags: gwt

Our standard module file is: Myproject.gwt.xml
We have added an extra modulefile for fast compilation called:
MyprojectWork.gwt.xml
When deploying to GAE, it compiles both Myproject.gwt.xml and
MyprojectWork.gwt.xml.

How to exclude MyprojectWork.gwt.xml from the compile, when deploying
to GAE ?

Config:
GWT SDK 1.7.0
Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5
GAE SDK 1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Maven than this may solve your problem: [stackoverflow #1745315](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745315/how-to-create-a-development-debug-and-production-setup)

Comment: Mentions Ant as well, so it should be possible. Haven't tried the example though, so it may or may not work. Thanks for the update.