# GWT gwt i18n Gin Module

Tags: gwt, internationalization, guice

My question is the following:

I got one application running with GWT.
At the startup of the application, one GWTClientModule which extends AbstractGinModule or another GWTClientModule is loaded.

Based on that switch I would like to set the local.
Is there a way to set the local not directly in .html by doing as follow:

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=fr">
```

but directly in one of the selected GWTClientModule?

Thank you very much for your kind assistance ;-)

Comment: Apparently there is only two ways to specify the locale: 1/ In the host page we define <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=x_Y">. 2/ by putting "?locale=fr" in the url. Is that true? No other way is possible on server side or using web.xml or in the gwtclientmodule or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that if you use [static String internationalization](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideStaticStringInternationalization), since it uses [deferred binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html): the GWT compiler generates one JavaScript file per locale, and, when your page is loaded, the GWT bootstrap script looks for the "locale" property inside the page (or in the URL), before loading the appropriate version of the code.

Choosing the locale programmatically (inside your GWTClientModule) is impossible, since the localized version of your code is *already* loaded once that code executes...

If you really need to choose the locale at runtime, you might want to look into [dynamic String internationalization](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization), but it is less performant and you lose static type checking.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'll look in the dynamic String internationalization at first sight. Or I can replace the .properties file during the build. Anyway, thanks for your explanation :-)

Comment: When you talk about replacing the .properties file during the build, I have to ask: what is your end goal? Do you simply want to compile for one specific locale?
Because you can do that easily by adding the following to your Module.gwt.xml:
    <set-property name="locale" value="fr_FR"/>
More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745315/how-to-create-a-development-debug-and-production-setup/1749507

Answer (score 0):

We used a workaround here based on [this](http://manolocarrasco.blogspot.ca/2009/11/gwt-client-side-vs-server-side-locale.html) to set the locale according to the client browsers language.

Simply add the following Javascript to your .html :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var search = location.search;  
if(search.indexOf("locale") == -1){  
    var lang = navigator.language!= null ? navigator.language : navigator.browserLanguage;  
    lang = lang.replace("-", "_");
    var metaTag = document.createElement('meta');
    metaTag.name = "gwt:property";
    metaTag.content = "locale=" + lang;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
}
</script>
```

It looks if the meta tag corresponding to the locale isn't set, if not it looks up the browser language and add the proper meta tag, EG :

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=fr">
```

Comment: This will not work for GWT for the reasons Etienne Neveu explains above. While using static string internationalization the text for the other locales is simply not available at all. It's hardcoded to the generated HTML/JS the GWT compilation generated for that specific permutation.

Comment: We used it in the internal project where I was working, did you try it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you were not using static string approach.